# FileMode.Open and FileMode.OpenOrCreate difference when file exists? c# bug?

Tags: c#, xml, serialization, xml-serialization, xmlserializer

I have wrote that code:

```
public void Save()
{
    using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(Properties.Settings.Default.settings_file_path, FileMode.Open))
    {
        XmlSerializer ser = new XmlSerializer(typeof(MySettings));
        ser.Serialize(fs, this);
    }
}
```

When I am using `FileMode.Open` everything is good, and output is e.x. like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<MySettings xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <settingsList>
        <Setting>
            <Value>12</Value>
            <Name>A0</Name>
            <Type>MEASUREMENT</Type>
        </Setting>
        <Setting>
            <Value>5000</Value>
            <Name>C0</Name>
            <Type>MEASUREMENT</Type>
        </Setting>
    </settingsList>
</MySettings>
```

but when I change it to `FileMode.OpenOrCreate` output will change to:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<MySettings xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <settingsList>
        <Setting>
            <Value>12</Value>
            <Name>A0</Name>
            <Type>MEASUREMENT</Type>
        </Setting>
        <Setting>
            <Value>5000</Value>
            <Name>C0</Name>
            <Type>MEASUREMENT</Type>
        </Setting>
    </settingsList>
</MySettings>>
```

what makes whole xml file corrupted because of additional `>` sign at the end.

Is this explanable or its c# bug?

Comment: @GrantWinney   Agree. FileModel.OpenOrCreate does not truncate the file. So writing to existing file may cause such behavior.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Deserialize an XML file - an error in xml document (11,12)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42270186/deserialize-an-xml-file-an-error-in-xml-document-11-12)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I have just reproduced that issue. 
As I wrote in comment.

> `FileMode.Open` erases contents of the file while `FileMode.OpenOrCreate` does not.

It seems that new content of the file is one char shorter than previous that's why you see ">" at the end.

If you are writing the file use `FileMode.Create` that should do for you.

Comment: Thanks for reply.
As i wrote- FIle.Open works perfectly for me but I was supposing that when file exists FIle.OpenOrCreate should work in the same way as FIle.Open and this post is about that

Comment: It does not and according to [link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filemode(v=vs.110).aspx) it is "as designed" behavior.