# Serializing to XML file creates invalid XML document (11,12)

Tags: c#, xml, serialization, xml-serialization, xmlserializer

I'm trying to save a class into an XML Document.
The class looks Like this:

```
public class Settings
{
    public LDAP LDAP;
    public Miscellaneous Miscellaneous;
}

public class LDAP
{
    public bool LoadLDAPData;
    public bool ShowLDAPRoutingMessage;
}

public class Miscellaneous
{
    public bool MinusBeforeQuestion;
    public bool MinusBeforeDescription;
}
```

The Data ist stored via this:

```
Settings MySettings = new Settings();
string MySettingsFile = @"settingsfile.xml";
...
FileStream outFile = File.Open(MySettingsFile, FileMode.OpenOrCreate);
XmlSerializer formatter = new XmlSerializer(MySettings.GetType());
formatter.Serialize(outFile, MySettings);
outFile.Close();
```

The Data is saved, but with one issue at the end:

```
<Settings...>
...
</Settings>>>
```

Can you tell me why?

Comment: This is a dupe. But simply solve it by  replacing `OpenOrCreate` with `Create`

Comment: @klashar - no, that one is not even close.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is happening because the content you are writing is shorter than the existing contents of the file, so some of the text is left at the end.

Instead of `FileMode.OpenOrCreate` (which opens the file and leaves its content intact if the file exists), use `FileMode.Create`:

```
FileStream outFile = File.Open(MySettingsFile, FileMode.Create);
```

Description of [`FileMode.Create`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filemode.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396):

> Specifies that the operating system should create a new file. If the file already exists, it will be overwritten. This requires FileIOPermissionAccess.Write permission. **FileMode.Create is equivalent to requesting that if the file does not exist, use CreateNew; otherwise, use Truncate.** If the file already exists but is a hidden file, an UnauthorizedAccessException exception is thrown.

Comment: Perfect, that worked.