# C# Delete Item from XML List

Tags: c#, xml, list, uwp

i write some UWP app. There i want to save/Update/Delete in a XML List. My XML List Looks like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<rootnode>
    <Kunde Name="Testkunde" />
    <Kunde Name="Testkunde2" />
</rootnode>
```

If i want to remove a item with this code

```
StorageFolder folder = await StorageFolder.GetFolderFromPathAsync(@"C:\Users\IT\source\repos\App3\App3");
StorageFile file = await folder.GetFileAsync("Kundenliste.xml");

using (IRandomAccessStream writeStream = await file.OpenAsync(FileAccessMode.ReadWrite))
{
    Stream s = writeStream.AsStreamForWrite();
    XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(s);

    var q = from node in doc.Descendants("Kunde")
        let attr = node.Attribute("Name")
        where attr != null && attr.Value == "Testkunde"
        select node;

    q.ToList().ForEach(x => x.Remove());
    doc.Save(s);
}
```

This happens

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<rootnode>
    <Kunde Name="Testkunde" />
  <Kunde Name="Testkunde2"  />
</rootnode><?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<rootnode>
  <Kunde Name="Testkunde2" />
</rootnode>
```

anyone can help me?

Comment: Before writing the `doc`, you need to rewind the `Stream` and clear its contents, e.g. by doing `s.Position = 0; s.SetLength(0)`.  See e.g. [FileMode.Open and FileMode.OpenOrCreate difference when file exists? c# bug?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29799265) for a similar bug in regular .Net.   I'm not sure whether the stream returned by `IRandomAccessStream.AsStreamForWrite();` can be repositioned and truncated though.

Comment: Or, for safety, you might write to a separate file and then do [`MoveAndReplaceAsync(Windows.Storage.IStorageFile)`](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/winrt-api/blob/docs/windows.storage/storagefile_moveandreplaceasync_1870118889.md).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just set

```
s.Position = 0;
s.SetLength(0);
```

after

```
Stream s = writeStream.AsStreamForWrite();
XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(s);
```

and it will works